# SQL error using INSERT INTO to build a table

Tags: sql, sas, enterprise-guide

I'm trying to put together a table in SAS Enterprise Guide using INSERT INTO using online tutorials but keep getting errors when I do the same thing as the tutorial. What could be going wrong?

My code:

```
/* Create the table */ 
   CREATE TABLE Summary_1920 (
      Variable VARCHAR(255), 
      Count INT, 
      Percentage FLOAT ); 
/* Create and insert the variable names */
   INSERT INTO Summary_1920 
      (Variable, Count, Percentage)
   VALUES 
      ("Variable1", 100, 90.8),
      ("Variable2", 8, 7.0);

QUIT;
```

The error:

```
28               ("IntName", 100, 90.8),
                                       _
                                       22
                                       200
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ;, VALUES.  

ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.
```

This is my first time using SAS EG/SQL so it's probably very obvious but I've been trying to fix this for ages. Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting.  It looks like `proc sql` doesn't allow you to insert multiple rows using a single `VALUES` clause.  So just use two statements:

```
INSERT INTO Summary_1920 (Variable, Count, Percentage)
    VALUES ("Variable1", 100, 90.8);

INSERT INTO Summary_1920 (Variable, Count, Percentage)
    VALUES ("Variable2", 8, 7.0);
```

I think it also supports multiple `VALUES` clauses in one statement:

```
INSERT INTO Summary_1920 (Variable, Count, Percentage)
    VALUES ("Variable1", 100, 90.8)
    VALUES ("Variable2", 8, 7.0);
```

This is not SQL standard syntax and I'm not familiar with any other database that supports it.  Your version with commas is standard -- or at least supported by most databases.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realise that different SQLs had different rules. I'll use your second clause there :)

Answer (score 0):

i think there is a limitation on your sql permissions, i tried your code and it works fine
[This is after the query executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WJJj.png)

- hower you can try inserting one by one and check if you experience the error again, try this:

  **CREATE TABLE Summary_1920 (
  Variable VARCHAR(255),
  Count INT,
  Percentage FLOAT );**

then also execute this


**INSERT INTO Summary_1920 (Variable, Count, Percentage)
VALUES ("Variable1", 100, 90.8);


INSERT INTO Summary_1920 (Variable, Count, Percentage)
VALUES ("Variable2", 8, 7.0);**